# In MVC view, when form is posted, request contains form values while all model fields are 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, post, model, controller

Using Visual Studio 2010, MVC project
When my form is submitted (currently via javascript, but same results with a submit button), the action is getting an empty model with both of the fields in it being zero instead of containing the value I entered into the textbox. The Request object does contain the correct name/value pair in the Form collection.

Model values going the other way work fine - so based on my [HttpGet] CallDisplayHome() action, the form loads with the textbox value being 1.

If anyone has a clue as to why it would not work coming back via POST, I would sure appreciate it.

Model being used:

```
namespace TCSWeb.Models
{
    public class CallDisplayModel
    {
        public int SelectedRowIndex;
        public int SelectedLineID;
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model TCSWeb.Models.CallDisplayModel

@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
/*
There a Jscript datatable here and a bunch of scripts for working with it in the header     I am skipping because I am hoping they are not relevant
*/

    <div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Testing", "CallDisplay", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "submitSelLine" }))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedLineID)    
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
        </p>        
    }    
    </div>    
    <button onclick="SubmitSelCallRecord()">@LangRes.Strings.calldisplay_opencallrecord</button>
```

My controller actions:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CallDisplayHome()
    {
        TCSWeb.Models.CallDisplayModel temper = new CallDisplayModel();
        temper.SelectedLineID = 1;
        temper.SelectedRowIndex = 1;
        return View(temper);
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Testing(TCSWeb.Models.CallDisplayModel cdmodel)
{
    return RedirectToAction("CallDisplayHome"); //breaking here, cmodel has zero for selectedlineid
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your CallDisplayModel variables as properties:

```
public int SelectedRowIndex { get; set; }

[Required]
public int SelectedLineID { get; set; }
```

You can also add a little bit of validation to make sure that the user provides the correct information.

Change your post method to the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Testing(TCSWeb.Models.CallDisplayModel temper)
{
    //check if valid
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //success!
        return RedirectToAction("CallDisplayHome"); 
    }
    //update error! redisplay form
    return View("CallDisplayHome", temper);

}
```

And display the errors in your view like so:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLineID)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedLineID)
```

I'm unsure what your submitSelCallRecord button is doing, as it is referencing the javascript that was omitted.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Worked perfectly.